# Oracle - Use of XMLType or Name=Value Pairs (EAV)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am working on designing a data model for log information.

The Log Information can have variable elements and that is very dynamic.

What type of data model should work better?
Use of XMLType column or an child table with Name=Value pairs?

I want to avoid creating multiple columns as they columns are dynamic by nature and can change very frequently.

I know EAV model is not very good for querying, but from what I have heard Oracle 11g provides a PIVOT function which can transpose rows to columns and so how would that impact performance?

The data loaded will be used for downstream ETL systems and also occasional querying by technical analysts

Thanks

---

Rajesh...
I plan to create 2 tables:

Parent table with common attributes which are part of every log event while the child table will have a parent table id (logId) and will have other transactional elements.

Currently there are 200 elements apart from standard elements and any log event can have unto 10 different elements. Also this number is very volatile and can change very frequently. It does not make sense to keep changing the table data structure every time there are new elements.

Also the data will not be stored for more than 7 days and the table is not going to be used (or occasional) for querying. There will be a downstream ETL job which will pull the data and perform flat file transforms.

I am not worried about the datatype because everything is string data. 
Do you see any concerns with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend towards columns for known, 'pretty much always there' stuff, and XML for any bits that were too individualistic for columns. XML is probably going to be easier for ETL to handle as long as there is some sort of schema to work with (possibly, but not necessarily, enforced by the database).

Comment: Have you used XMLType data type in oracle? How is the performance for XMLType for querying?

Answer (score 0):

EAV models ( very quickly) get too complex to Query, even with Pivot statements. Sub Queries, nested Queries and Joins will be difficult to write and understand and will be less performant.

Apart from Performance, you cannot guarantee that the data is being stored correctly (date is in Date column, number in number column.. and so on). This will mean you store everything in Strings and convert it back to the correct data type hoping it was inserted correctly the first time. Read this document for various side effects. 
http://antognini.ch/papers/DatatypesWorstPractices_20080509.pdf

Even in the case of logging, there are a few common parameters that you want to track for most of the logs and only a few that are specific to some logs. Creating a table with NULLLable columns for those special fields is a better approach. You can always index the most important fields and you can build views specific to a particular type of logs if you wish to see/expose only some fields.

Comment: Rajesh I have updated the question. Your thoughts will be very helpful on this